# How to pass the parameter to which an object needs to be cast to

Tags: apex, schema, casting

I have the following piece of code where I wish to cast a certain object to a specific SObjectType.

```
public static void someMethod(Object obj, Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectType){
        ...
        Map<String, Object>v = ((objectType) obj).getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
        ...
}
```

where `objectType` should be something like `Account`, `Custom_Obj__c` etc.:

```
Map<String, Object>v = ((Account) obj).getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
```

But passing `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult` does not work. What is the data type that should be passed in the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically cast in Apex. Fortunately, here, you don't need to.

Type `obj` as an `Sobject` value, rather than `Object`. The [`getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) method is defined on the sObject class, so you can call it regardless of what concrete sObject your method receives.

If you do need to write distinct logic for different sObject types, you can use a [`switch on`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_switch.htm) construction. Example from the linked document:

```
switch on sobject {
   when Account a {
       System.debug('account ' + a);
   }
   when Contact c {
       System.debug('contact ' + c);
   }
   when null {
       System.debug('null');
   }
   when else {
       System.debug('default');
   }
}
```

Comment: `Object obj` is not something I can control, but I added `(Sobject) obj` and it worked. Hope I'm not violating any ethics.